# set curent transform as default

Tags: transforms

I've made a model from a copy of another object, but now it's done I just see now that it's rotation angles weren't set to 0. 
And now it causes me trouble when I mirror it.
Is there a way to "Zero-ing" the current rotation as if it's a normal one?

Comment: *CTRL + A > Rotation* should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Oh thanks it worked : It didn't originally because i Had a delta transform changed too, but now it's good. thanks again ! :D